# add buttons at the end of selected listview item in android dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listview in which my list contain textview,means I have a list of text where user can select the text, read it and set margin note at the end of that text and a button is created over there. So when next time the user read that text then the button/buttons is there and when click on that button a popup is open where he can see his margin note.
Now the problem is that he can create more than one margin note at the end. In this case I have to create one or more button dynamically at the end of that selected textview. So please help me I am unable to create more than one button dynamically.

Comment: Button btn = new Button(this);
   btn.setText("login");
   btn.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: Thank you.But by using this i can add buttons dynamically but next time they are not visible at right place.suppose i add the button at textview whose postion is 3.now when i scroll listview then button postion is changed and its moves to any other postion

Comment: whats ur requriment tel me..i wil solve ur problem,,what ur trying to do

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

1) Create the buttons (max the user will require) already in the xml file of the list item element and set their visibility to invisible or gone. When the user selects it you can set the visibility to visible. The visibility can be set dynamically.

2) The other way is to add buttons programatically. List views do reuse views for performance purposes. this could explain as to why you are having trouble with the button moving positions. in this case you have identify the id of the list item and add and remove buttons every time the view is created in your getView method of your list adapter.

- Remember to chk the condition on your getView method and set visibility or add/remove button.

Comment: Please accept this as an answer if it worked for you. Will be helpful for others with the same question.

Comment: Thank you...I can be done by using list item id..thanks a lot Gan

Comment: i tried this but i fail to add buttons dynamically because the button position is changed after scrolling.

Comment: how are you adding your buttons when the user selects an item (what are the conditions you are checking (remember, if the id does not match, and if the button exists, you have to remove it.). please share you code so i can precisely see whats happening.

If you are not successful with the 2nd method, try the first method that i have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
            System.out.println("I clicked row item");
            button1= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setVisibility(button1.isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);}
```